# Is it possible to install a usb wireless adapter on windows 7 without admin access or third-party drivers?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

My wife has a laptop for her work-from-home job and the wireless card has failed. Her work "does not support wireless" so they won't fix it and she is very unhappy being corded. I can not open the box to replace the card as I do not own the computer. I also do not have Admin access to install a driver.

Is it possible to use any usb to wifi (N preferably) dongle and have it "just work" plug and play in Windows 7? What "Product Specifications" would indicate native compatibility?

Comment: Nope, you need drivers and admin rights. Would using ethernet be an option?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, I think I can use ethernet as it is working that way now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a driver to use any hardware that's not there now, and even for an automatic install you probably need admin rights.

You might be able to use an ethernet wifi bridge ([google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=ethernet%20wifi%20bridge&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=cMehU_b6K8LLrQfRr4CABw)) if you absolutely need wireless access - this can be a dedicated device or a computer of some sort set up appropriately. For the latter option, you may need bridge tools in linux or just bridging [connections in windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7) on a second system you have admin rights on.

Comment: Ah brilliant! I'm going to try it.

Comment: I bought a dedicated wireless-n bridge worked, my wife thanks you!